# python - hide IE browser in selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

How can I hide the Internet Exploer(IE) in selenium in windows and using send keys without opening browser?

some ways I tried didn't work on windows or when sending keys, it will show browser...

Comment: Why do you want to hide `Internet Exploer(IE)`?

Comment: I want do some tasks together